# Replacement for _dispSolutionEvents_ProjectAddedEventHandler

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-addins, vs-extensibility, extensibility

I am migrating an existing add-in to an extension targeting `VS2017`.

In this process i started converting converting `DTE` events to `IVsSolutionEvents`. Then i came across `_dispSolutionEvents_ProjectAddedEventHandler` event. But i could not find an appropriate replacement in `IVsSolutionEventsX`.

Does any one know its replacement or how can i get an event when a project is added in solution other than the DTE Event?

Answer (score 1):

[IVsSolutionEvents.OnAfterOpenProject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionevents.onafteropenproject.aspx) has the **fAdded** parameter that is  **true** if the project is added to the solution.